# CORS not working for a request made inside a javascript file

Tags: firefox, cors, apache2.4

I have CORS configured for my static subdomain and I can use the static files in my main domain and subdomains.

The problem is that I have a get request inside a javascript file and firefox is complaining only for that request, that is to the same static subdomain than the rest of requests I made on the html code.

I don't remember having this problem before, maybe some change in CORS (firefox) made this not work anymore?

The script (from inside the .js file):

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    //[...]
    language: {
        "url": "//static.domain.com/js/DataTables-Spanish.json"
    },
    //[...]
} );
```

This is what it actually does, a jquery ajax request method:

```
if ( oLanguage.sUrl !== "" )
{
    /* Get the language definitions from a file - because this Ajax call makes the language
     * get async to the remainder of this function we use bInitHandedOff to indicate that
     * _fnInitialise will be fired by the returned Ajax handler, rather than the constructor
     */
    $.ajax( {
        dataType: 'json',
        url: oLanguage.sUrl,
        success: function ( json ) {
            _fnLanguageCompat( json );
            _fnCamelToHungarian( defaults.oLanguage, json );
            $.extend( true, oLanguage, json );
            _fnInitialise( oSettings );
        },
        error: function () {
            // Error occurred loading language file, continue on as best we can
            _fnInitialise( oSettings );
        }
    } );
    bInitHandedOff = true;
}
```

The error in the firefox console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://static.mydomain.com/js/DataTables-Spanish.json. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

The CORS config (inside the vhost block):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase Origin: "https?://(www\.)?(domain\.com|sub1\.domain\.com)(:\d+)?$" ACAO=$0
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "%{ACAO}e" env=ACAO
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET"
</IfModule>
```

Again, as you can see CORS is properly configured in the static subdomain, and I only get the complain for a request that is inside a javascript file.

Why is firefox complaining?

## Firefox network monitor

```
Status: 200 - Method: GET - File: DataTables-Spanish.json - Domain: (green lock) static.domain.com - Cause: script - Type: json 

-Request headers:

Host: static.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.7,es;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://sub1.domain.com/site
Origin: https://sub1.domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

-Response headers:

Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 932
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 06 Jan 2017 02:34:49 GMT
Etag: "3a4-52ef9645b6940"
Last-Modified: Sat, 26 Mar 2016 20:19:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
access-control-allow-methods: GET
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;
```

EDIT: It works ok if I use the wildcard instead of the regex in the config:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Origin: "https?://(www\.)?(domain\.com|sub1\.domain\.com)(:\d+)?$" ACAO=$0
    #Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "%{ACAO}e" env=ACAO
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET"
</IfModule>
```

<s>So now the question is: why is it not working with the regex?</s>

<s>It'll work with the regex if I put that header in the last line</s>:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "https://(www.domain.com|sub1.domain.com|auth.domain.com)$" ACAO=$0
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
    Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ACAO}e" env=ACAO
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is the CORS header present if you call the DataTables-Spanish.json file directly in your browser?

Comment: When I do a ctrl+F5 yeah. I was thinking, maybe the function doesn't do a get method?

Comment: Ok, now try your code again … does it work now? Maybe you just had some old header in the cache.

Comment: No, it keeps complaining and that's really weird, cuz I can see the headers (`access-control-allow-methods:"GET"`) in the page where it complains.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I said "When I do a ctrl+F5" because when the status code is 304 not modified the cors headers are not received again (for all files, not just the json).

Comment: I just added the actual ajax request code and found where the problem is, but I'd like to only allow my domain/subdomains in the allow-origin header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I took the code from another question and didn't noticed the following:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase
```

That was doing just the opposite of what I wanted, that is whitelist the domains in the regex:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "https://(www.domain.com|sub1.domain.com|auth.domain.com)$" ACAO=$0
Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ACAO}e" env=ACAO
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
```

The other html requests are not supposed to be blocked by cors, so that's why.